# Is there a way to automatically align UVs via shortest edge?

Tags: uv

Is there a way to automatically align UVs via shortest edge? I want to lay these steps out longways so they use the wood trim section. I can do each manually, snapping to vertex, but it takes a while and doesn't scale with more steps.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked for, but if you select all faces and press U > Reset, every face will be mapped to the whole UV space, so it becomes fast and easy to edit them, not one by one but using groups of similar faces (rotation can be unpredictable, so there can be 4 different orientations in the UV space).

Then you can move some faces to get variations.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that might work. Is there any way to do that while preserving or restoring each face's aspect ratio afterwards? currently it stretches to fill the UV space.

Comment: I ended up using this method. I left one face untouched and used that as a reference to scale the others back into proportion.